# Why x ~/ y is more efficient than (x / y).toInt()

Tags: flutter, dart

If I write `(x/y).toInt()` in flutter it suggests me to use `x~/y` as its efficient.

[image: ide hint]

I have two queries regarding this.

1. Why `~/` is faster.
2. What is this `~/` operator called.

**NB:** See official docs of `~/` [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html)

**UPDATE:**
Please check this benchmark https://dartpad.dev/b6e809ceaf52e80ee7e78b3c940e5d5f

Comment: As an answer to query 2, from the link you provided, it is a "Truncating division operator."

Comment: because `(x/y).toInt()` creates 2 objects? double converted to int, while `x~/y` gives you int directly - but honestly in practice it is the same

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess for huge data it can be a difference. @pskink

Comment: Benchmarking division operations I discovered that ```(x~/y)``` take more time to get executed than ```(x/y).toInt()```. Even using ```Float32x4``` SIMD computations. In general, truncation is very expensive. 

I was working in an animation library, since you only has 16 ms before frames begin to get skipped, performance were very important.

Comment: Could you provide some results of your benchmark @GaurisJavier. May be an screenshot url?

Comment: Take a look at the average benchmarking result after running operation 100,000 times (using benchmark_harness):

```var integerDivision = t ~/ step; //13.561790540540540562 ms```

```var toInt = (t / step).toInt(); //1.4831208302446257097 ms```

```var truncate = (t / step).truncate(); //2.6906209677419354875 ms```

```var float32x4 = (Float32x4.splat(t) / Float32x4.splat(step)).x.truncate(); //2.7064641407307168386 ms```

[Inline Link](https://imgur.com/a/S48JKmw)

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/b6e809ceaf52e80ee7e78b3c940e5d5f 
See we have a clear winner. I used your code only to benchmark this @GaurisJavier